# Google Sheets: Creating a formatted list based off Form Results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I am working on a voting form to rank some things (A, B, C, D, F) using Google Forms. I have it set up to import the results into Google Sheets. What I am trying to do is to then take the results and sort them in another sheet by their rankings.

So the result of the form looks something like this:

| Item A | Item B | Item C | Item D | Item E | Item F | Item G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | F | C | F | A | F |
| B | C | F | C | D | A | F |
| B | A | D | C | F | A | F |
| B | B | D | C | D | B | F |

I then have a formula that finds the majority ranking for each item and places them into another sheet, which looks like this:

| Item A | Item B | Item C | Item D | Item E | Item F | Item G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | B | D | C | D | A | F |

My goal is to have the final sheet transpose that table and sort them alphabetically by their voted upon ranking. So using the dataset above, it would look like this:

| Rank A | Rank B | Rank C | Rank D | Rank F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item F | Item A | Item D | Item C | Item G |
|  | Item B |  | Item E |  |

Is this something that is possible to automate in Google Sheets? Currently I am doing the last part manually, but I would love to have it auto-add each ranked item to the correct column and if possible, sort them alphabetically in their respective ranks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 QUERY(TEXT(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:G2, " ", "×")), {"@", "Rank×@"}), 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), " ")), "×", " "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created this example, you will need to change the ranges in the formula to match with your data.

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(FILTER(A1:G1, A2:G2 = "A")))
```

Add the above formula below each “Rank” column and change the letter “A” to the respective ranking.

[image]